# How do I loop through a named regex groups using Bash scripts

Tags: regex, bash

I need to walk through all regex named groups in a file

Let's say I'd like to use a regex `Basic (?<auth-token>\w+=?=?)` which finds all authentications tokens in a file, e.g. it should capture token from next block

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: Basic hsoghiapshgosahgklsrjglskrjgekrjgsarrg=" ...
```

I would like to loop using bash script through all these tokens. How I can do this?

Comment: Bash uses [POSIX Extended Regular Expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04), which do not support named capture groups. Groups are stored in the `BASH_REMATCH` array. The first element is the full text of the matched RE, the second element the first group, and so on.

Comment: @Shawn many thanks for your reply. I will try to use BASH_REMATCH.